# How to show multiple items of same time in FirebaseDatabase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am building a calendar app and I have developed it so that when you click on a date it will show the event corresponding to that date. I have it so that the date will appear in the tableview and when you click on the event it will then segue to a detail view controller and show the details of that event. I am stuck because I am not sure how to get firebase to load multiple events onto one date or how to show multiple events with the same date.

My Code:

View Did Load:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        calendar.dataSource = self
        calendar.delegate = self
        
        self.calendar.calendarHeaderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
        calendar.appearance.titleWeekendColor = UIColor.red
        
        
        retrieveEventsFromDatabase()
        print(eventsArray)
        

    }
```

How I am getting the Data:

```
func retrieveEventsFromDatabase() {
        dbReference = Database.database().reference().child("calendarevents")
        dbReference.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in
            
            guard snapshot.childrenCount > 0 else { return }
            
            var events: [EventsDataModel] = []
            for event in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
            {
                let object = event.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                
                let eventName = object?["eventName"]
                let eventDate = object?["eventDate"]
                let eventColor = object?["eventColor"]
                
                let event = EventsDataModel(eventName: eventName as! String, eventDate: eventDate as! String,eventColor: eventColor as! String)
                
                
                events.append(event)
                self?.eventsArray = events
                //print(events)
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.eventsTable.reloadData()
                self?.calendar.reloadData()
            }
        })
        
    }
```

How i am showing it in my table and calendar:

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
        
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        let dateString = self.dateFormatter2.string(from: date)
        
        
        print("selected dateString = \(dateString)")
        tableArray.removeAll()
        
        for event in eventsArray {
            if event.eventDate.contains(dateString) {
                selectedDateLabel.text = ("The selected date is \(dateString)")
                print("The event for this date is \(event.eventName)")
                
                tableArray.append(event)
                
                break;
            } else {
                selectedDateLabel.text = "select a date to see the events for this day"
                print("=select a date to see the events for this day")
            }
        }
        
        
        self.eventsTable.reloadData()

    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       
        let friend = tableArray[indexPath.row].eventName
        
        let cell = eventsTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventCell", for: indexPath) as! EventsTitleTableViewCell
        cell.eventTitleLabel?.text = friend

        return cell
    }
```

Firebase Database:

```
{
  "2021-01-12" : {
    "eventColor" : "red",
    "eventDate" : "2021-01-12",
    "eventName" : "SignUp Day"
  },
  "2021-01-15" : {
    "eventColor" : "red",
    "eventDate" : "2021-01-15",
    "eventName" : "First Day"
  },
  "electionday" : {
    "eventColor" : "red",
    "eventDate" : "2021-02-20",
    "eventName" : "Election Day "
  },
  "groundhogday" : {
    "eventColor" : "red",
    "eventDate" : "2021-02-20",
    "eventName" : "GroundHog Day"
  }
}
```

Picture of my App for more details:

[image]

Comment: Please consider showing the code where you upload the table view and how you fetch datas

Comment: I am sorry. I originally thought it may have been more of a firebase question so i did not upload the code. I have updated my question. I hope this can help explain my request better. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anybody that is looking at this in the future. I want to answer my own question. For any references I was using this with FSCalendar and Firebase. The answer to my question was that there was a "break;" as seen after the tableArray(append). That was only allowing one of my events to show on the table. When i commented that out, then both the events would show on my table. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think that a better and more logical approach would be to store the event, rather than dates, and then every event has a corresponding date.
When the user taps on the day, you fetch all the events that have the date property equal to that date.

Comment: I have edited my firebase to show two events that are labeled by their names instead of the dates. when I run the code. It will still only show one of the events in my table. It will not show both. Could there be an issue in the code that i posted that wont allow it to show more than one? Thanks